# Elliptical cylinder surface area | Analytic geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I'm struggling to understand how to solve this kind of problems:

I have to find the **equation** of a **Cylindrical surface area**.
This area has the generating **lines** **parallel** to the axis **$z$**.
The directrix is an **ellipse** on the floor $Oxy$ with center **$C(1;3;0)$** and vertices **$A(1;-1;0)$, $B(-1;3;0)$**.

---

I tried to make a system with:

- $a = 2$ // As the distance from the center and the $B$ vertex is $2$
- changed $X$ and $Y$ values with those of the vertex $A$ first
- and then with those of the vertex $B$.

  ---

I now have a system of $3$ equations with variables $a$ and $b$, but they're **squared** only, as they're supposed to be in an ellipse.

I tried to solve it but it doesn't look good as the solution has parameters $x $and $y$ not squared as well.

**Solution: $4x^2 + y^2 -x -6y -3 = 0$**

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to find an equation for the cylinder itself or for the surface area of the cylinder? The title thing but your proposed solution does something else.

Comment: I'm looking for the equation of the surface area @amd

Comment: Apparently it has to be done with translations. That's why we have the parameter x and y not squared on the answer

Comment: You’ve got the equation of an elliptical cylinder there, but in both the question’s title and body, you say that you want its *surface area*. So, what’s really your question?

Comment: The text asks me the equation of the cylindrical surfaces @amd, look

Comment: That’s not surface *area*, however. Please update your question to clarify what you’re actually asking.

Comment: About to update with a picture

Comment: Don’t include important information as an image. It’s not searchable and is inaccessible to people using screen readers. If you’re not going to take the time to enter this information, why do you expect us to take our time to help you?

Comment: @amd I understand the picture is in Italian but the highlighted text says "Cylindrical surfaces"

Comment: I don't know how to tell you this is what the exercise is asking me: find the equation of these cylindrical surfaces.

Comment: Thus, as I've already written above, the exercise has to be done using translations, so here's the answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few hints:

- Asking you to find the equation of a surface in three dimensions is something of a red herring. Its generating lines are parallel to the $z$-axis and the directrix ellipse lies entirely in the $x$-$y$ plane, so the equation of the elliptical cylinder will look exactly like the equation of the (two-dimensional) ellipse.
- You’re on the right track by subtracting the center from the two vertices. You should find from this that the axes of the ellipse are parallel to the $x$- and $y$-axes, so in a coordinate system in which the ellipse is at the origin, its equation is $(x'/a)^2+(y'/b)^2=1$.
- To translate the center of the ellipse to a point $(x_c,y_c)$, make the substitutions $x'\to x-x_c$ and $y'\to y-y_c$ in the equation you derived for the ellipse centered at the origin.

Comment: Ooh you're right! Thank you! I have the test now, hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you again! The test was totally fine! The surface area was a parabola though, much easier 